# Using laravel localization in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using typeahead in my Laravel project. I have in a file called main translations. Now I want to use __trans or @lang function in code. I mean that place where is __trans(data.name) because that is not working. In the database I have:

[image: DB]

```
suggestion: function (data) {
          return '<li class="list-group-item">' + __trans(data.name) + '</li>'
}
```

Comment: This won't work. You would need to make an ajax call to the server to transliterate the data, or you would need to integrate client-side transliteration.

Comment: So what's the easiest way to do it? maybe you have any tutorial?

Comment: **easiest** is subjective as I have no idea your skill set. Maybe you can look into some tutorials on javascript transliteration or internationalization in general. Those are good starting points.